# Python last iteration not giving proper output

Tags: python, pandas

I have 410 ids in list m:

```
m=list(range(0,len(plist['No']), 20))

for i in range(len(m))):

    t = tuple(plist.loc[m[i]:m[i+1],'No'])
    query ="select * from table where ID IN {}".format(t)

    temp=pd.read_sql(query,conn)

    df = df.append(temp)
```

`for` loop iterate for 20 times, but for the last iteration I got error of list index i out of range.

Comment: Always be careful when you write `i+1`. Think about what that's trying to index.

Comment: how can i write that code without using i+1

Comment: To start with, you could add an exception when `i == len(m)-1`.